# use pandas to retrieve files over FTP

Tags: ftp, pandas, unzip, gunzip

I'm just getting to grips with pandas (which is awesome) and what I need to do is read in compressed genomics type files from ftp sites into a pandas dataframe.
This is what I tried and got a ton of errors:

```
from pandas.io.parsers import *

chr1 = 'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/snp/organisms/human_9606/chr_rpts/chr_1.txt.gz'

CHR1 = read_csv(chr1, sep='\t', compression = 'gzip', skiprows = 10)

print type(CHR1)
print CHR1.head(10)
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
from pandas.io.data import *
AAPL = DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start = '01/01/2006')
```

Comment: I don't think pandas are intelligent enough to retrieve files using FTP.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part of this question is how to *stream a (gz) file from ftp*, which is discussed [here](http://www.enricozini.org/2011/cazzeggio/python-gzip/), where it's claimed that the following will work in Python **3.2** (but [won't in 2.x, nor will it be backported](http://bugs.python.org/issue11608)), and on my system this is the case:

```
import urllib.request as ur
from gzip import GzipFile

req = ur.Request(chr1) #  gz file on ftp (ensure startswith 'ftp://')
z_f = ur.urlopen(req)

# this line *may* work (but I haven't been able to confirm it)
# df = pd.read_csv(z_f, sep='\t', compression='gzip', skiprows=10)

# this works (*)
f = GzipFile(fileobj=z_f, mode="r")
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', skiprows=10)
```

(*) Here `f` is "file-like", in the sense that we can perform a `readline` (read it line-by-line), rather than having to download/open the entire file.

.

*Note: I couldn't get the [`ftplib` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) to `readline`, it wasn't clear whether it ought to.*